# Complexity of multiplying two integers of size $n$ and $m$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

The multiplication of two integers of size $n$ can be done in time $O(n \cdot \log n \cdot \log\log n)$ using FFT method.

If the two integers have different sizes $n$ and $m$, does a smaller upper bound using $n$ and $m$ exists ?

Comment: If you replace $n$ in the upper bound you gave with $\max(n, m)$ (or equivalently with $n+m$), you get *an* upper bound for the different-sizes case, since you can always left-pad the smaller number with zeros; you could even replace it with, say, $n^3m^7$ and this would give you *an* upper bound.  If those aren't satisfying answers, then you're probably looking for the *smallest known* upper bound.  (Which I don't know, sorry.)

Comment: If $m = O(1)$ then the answer is $O(n)$. So there's probably a nontrivial tradeoff.

Comment: Do the convolutional methods actually require $m=n$?

Comment: One thing to try, assuming $n\ge m$, is to reduce to $n/m$ products of $m$-bit numbers (followed by the requisite additions).

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication of two integers of size $n$ and size $m$ in base-2 with $n\le m$ can be done in time 
$$O(m\cdot\log n\cdot\log\log n)$$ 
where the product will be given in base-2 as well.

Here is a sketch of the simple idea to prove the above claim.

---

Let positive integer $a$ has $n$ digits and positive integer $b$ have $m$ digits in base 2. For simplicity, let $m=kn$ for some integer $k$. 
$$b=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}b_{i,j}2^{in+j}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{in}b_i$$ 
where $0\le b_{i,j}\le1$, $b_i=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}b_{i,j}2^j$. In other words, $b_{k-1}\cdots b_1b_0$ is $b$ in base-$2^n$.
So $$ab= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{in}(ab_i).$$

Since both $a_i$ and $b_i$ have $n$ digits, the product $ab_i$ can be computed in $O(n\cdot\log n\cdot\log\log n)$ (using FFT method). Multiplying by factor $k=\dfrac mn$, we see that all summands in the above equality and hence $ab$ can be computed in $O(m\cdot\log n\cdot\log\log n)$. Note that the computation cost of various bookkeeping and additions is not substantial enough to invalidate that bound.

---

<sub>This idea of splitting the bits of the bigger number by the length of the bits of the smaller number is articulated here first in [Yuval's comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/103044?#comment-220090). That idea is, apparently, folklore among users experienced in algorithms.</sub>

<sub>If we have a smaller bound for the multiplication of the integers of the same size, we will get a smaller bound for the multiplication of integers of different sizes accordingly. For example, [an algorithm by Harvey and van der Hoeven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm) gives bound $O(n\log n\cdot 2^{2\log ^{*}n})$. So we will have bound $O(m\log n\cdot 2^{2\log ^{*}n})$ accordingly.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is a trivial upper bound O (n * m). If m = o (log n log log n) then this is better than O (n log n log log n).

I think it will be very hard to beat O (max (n*m, n log n log log n)) for m ≤ n.

PS. Wrong, wrong, wrong: Look at apass.jack's answer. Of course if you have say n = 1,000,000 and m = 100,000 then there isn't much savings.